# How to making an animation with color changes in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner in unity, so bear with me.

On my screen I've several instances of park guarded with electrical fences.
Each park has a different sprite, but otherwise, they are coming from the same prefab.

On one event, I need to shutdown the electricity of all the parks.
Currently, I've a GameObject with a script that has the list of all the park. When the events comes, it calls a method on each park. Each park then just change their tint to "red" indicate they are shutdown.

I've reproduced this in a minimal example:

```
public class Game : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] Park[] Parks;


    public void ShutdownEverything()
    {
        foreach (Park park in Parks)
        {
            park.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

and my parks:

```
public class Park : MonoBehaviour
{

    public void Shutdown()
    {
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.red;
    }
}
```

There is several things I'm trying to do now:

1. How to animate this shutdown? I was thinking of the fence "blinking"(like when the power goes out in movies). But how do I program this ? I've never done stuff that will implies several frames?
2. I need to wait the end of the animation to start shutdown the next park, how to do this

Comment: You could litterally create an animation using Unitys animation editor, coding things like that isn't always the best way

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm quite in the beginning of my unity adventure. I will take a look to the animation editor. Just to be sure, I will still be able to trigger this animation from the code? The change is coming from the network

Comment: No worries and yes the object with the animation/s you want to trigger will need an Animator component and that will need an AnimationController with all the Animations in with the names you want to use in code. then from the code once you have the Animator you call it like `animator.Play("AnimName");`

Comment: Have a look in the Asse Store for for a package called DOTween.

Comment: @Immersive That seems awesome, I'm not sure how I can have a "sequence" for each park, then at the game level, wait on a sequence to finish to trigger the next one? Do you know how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this. The first one is with a Coroutine if you want it blink for a little amount of time: you can do it in this way

```
IENumerator ColorBlink(GameObject park, float TimeToBlink)
 { 
      park.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.red;
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(TimeToBlink);
      park.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.blue; //or any default
       // and you can do it the times you want
 }
```

I suggest also a change to that coroutine if you want it to play lots of time:

```
IENumerator ColorBlinkMore(GameObject park, float TimeToBlink,int timeBlinked)
 { 
      for(int i = 0; i <= timeBlinked; i++)
     {  
      park.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.red;
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(TimeToBlink);
      park.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.blue; //or any default
     } //it is going to blink for timeBlinked times
 }
```

Remember to call this coroutine in this way

```
StartCoroutine(ColorBlinkMore(park[2], 0.1f, 15)) //this is going to make the park[2] blink and change color for 15 times
```

If you don't like the code way you can also create an animation in each park with an idle state of the normal color and a blinking state when you change the color from sprite renderer when you press record. Then via code, you can start that animation and go back to idle after an amount of time.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer! Is there a way to have easing between the on and off color? Like cubic or similar?

Comment: You can use Color.lerp , you can learn more from this Unity Doc : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.Lerp.html

Comment: Thanks, I've documented myself on the coroutine, seems nice! I will read your link about "Lerp" One question though:

I've understood how to have some kind of sequence which will allow me to blink. I think the best place is in the "Park". But then in the "Game", how to wait that the coroutine of park 1 is finished before triggering the one of the park 2?

Comment: About Lerp: It means that I've to "interpolate" myself the colors? Isn't there some way to say that I want to go from blue to red in 2 seconds with a cubic easing?

Comment: You can go from a color to another with the documentation I have linked to you before (Color.Lerp) and if you want to run a Coroutine just after another one you can use a system of bool control or a Coroutine inside a coroutine. I don't know precisely your game so it's about you

Comment: Yes i understand, but there has to be some tweening available, no? Especially this apply to every "transition" we can make: Opacity, scaling, color, .... ? I've found this: http://dotween.demigiant.com/ . Maybe it means that Unity doesn't do this by default?

Comment: Obviously, it is not a default feature, but it's something you can get with different methods inside scripting. I suggest to try with coroutines or animations, it should be fine. Was I useful?

Comment: ? Why obviously? Phaser3, which is much less advanced has this by default. You're definitely usefull, but I still don't see how to coordinates the coroutine of each park to make sure one doesn't start before the previous one has finished?

Comment: If you want a certain loop you can use a big coroutine to make coroutine start and so it will go in anyway you like. If you want to play just one at time you can set a bool at the end of the coroutine as false and at the start to true so while it's playing nothing can start if you put it as a condition